# Custom sorting algorithm c++

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting, overwrite

I was tinkering with C++ and I was like `let's make a sorting algorithm` :)

I did something, but it didn't sort the array but instead the array was overwritten with the max number

I don't know where is my mistake because I ran the algorithm on paper (don't ask) and it was correct.

I tried every modification possible.
any help?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int mn = 0, mx = 0;
    int a[] = { 4, 8, 5, 2, 6, 9, 0, 3, 1, 7 };

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        mn = a[i]; mx = a[i];
        for (int j = i; j < 10 - i; j++)
        {
            mn = min(a[j], mn);
            mx = max(a[j], mx);
        }
        swap(a[i], mn);
        swap(a[10-1-i], mx);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        cout<<a[i]<<" ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not swapping array elements, but basically you write the min/max values to the corresponding places within the array. Their old value is simply overwritten. You need to track the positions of the min/max elements and swap accordingly, e.g. `swap(a[i], a[min_pos])`. Additionally, you could run your outer loop up until the middle of the array is reached as you put two elements into their place on each iteration.

Here's the working code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int mn = 0, mx = 0;
    int a[] = { 4, 8, 5, 2, 6, 9, 0, 3, 1, 7 };

    for (int i = 0; i < 10 / 2; i++)
    {
        int min_pos = i, max_pos = i;

        for (int j = i; j < 10 - i; j++)
        {
            if (a[j] < a[min_pos]) {
                min_pos = j;
            } else if (a[j] > a[max_pos]) {
                max_pos = j;
            }
        }

        int min_val = a[min_pos];
        int max_val = a[max_pos];

        swap(a[i], a[min_pos]);
        swap(a[10-1-i], a[max_pos]);

        a[i] = min_val;
        a[10-1-i] = max_val;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        cout<<a[i]<<" ";
    }
}
```

Note, you need to take care of 'special cases', e.g. when the `min_pos` and `max_pos` are at the ends of the interval - they would be swapped twice staying in their original positions.

Comment: output -> (expected) 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
(reality) 0,8,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,9

Comment: @darijan2002 There's of course a lot of room for improvement but at least you know the corner cases where it went wrong :)

Comment: @darijan2002 Think of the second iteration of your algorithm. `i == 1`, `min_pos == 8`, `max_pos == 1`. Then you swap elements 1 and 8 and then swap 8 and 1 effectively leaving the array in the same state. That's why I store the values. Or you could check if this case occurs by replacing these lines with `if (!(min_pos == 10-1-i && max_pos == i)) {              swap(a[i], a[min_pos]); }  swap(a[10-1-i], a[max_pos]);`
`

Comment: ok anyway thanks I wanted to make a modification of selection sort and cocktail shake sort